# Python requests code from Postman is not working

Tags: python, python-requests

I've used postman for getting the access token from server and it's working fine. but when i copy the python code from postman and run that code in IDE it's showing some errors like max entries exceeded.

import requests

url = "https://web.com/oauth/token"

payload = "type=authorizatio&code=mycode&id=abcdefghi&client=kjsisjnsui675eaa9WqksiisP"
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)

Comment: *some errors*, are there more then just max entries?

Comment: You should make `payload` a dictionary.... `payload = {'type': 'authorization', 'code': 'mycode'...}`

Comment: changed the payload to dictionary. but no luck.. Any proxy related issue behind this error : requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<>', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /oauth/token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000431E2B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'

Comment: You could try increasing the timeout by `requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, timeout=60) # wait 60 seconds`... but if that doesn't work... you've probably got some glitches in the line :)

Comment: it's working fine now.the actual issue is with n/w or proxy settings. Thanks @JonClements